# Normal and Editing views/template for block

Tags: template, blocks, ee-1.13, edit-order

I'm redesigning a small part of a website which previously had a set of customer account items which were directly editable simply by showing the textboxes/inputs, radio buttons, checkboxes, etc, directly.

Now I need to have two different views of the same block: one for normal viewing and one for editing said information.

This is to occur on the frontend.

So, this is what I have now:

[image: Normal View]

And this is what I intend to achieve when clicking in `Endre` (means Edit):
[image: Edit View]

I don't know how I'll implement the behaviour shown in the second image, but since I need to "fade" the background view (the darker part) I'm guessing I should be doing it via a Modal Box and an AJAX request to this view/template.

Am I correct to assume this? And how should I go about creating this edit view? What do I need to insert into my `local.xml` and what's the best way of doing this? Having a different template (.phtml file) for this view?

Comment: Is this adminhtml or frontend?

Comment: @TimHallman it's frontend.. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: @TimHallman, no ideas?

Comment: Do you need to dynamically grab the form via AJAX?  Does the form already exist when the page loads and it just needs to be "shown" to the user?  Do you need to perform an AJAX update or just a form submit?  Let me know and I'll advise the best path.

Comment: Hello @RyanStreet, I was thinking of grabbing the form dynamically (when needed) but I'm confortable with either way. The reason I'm thinking of loading it dynamically if to achieve the modal box effect with the faded background. The update can be done via ajax (I'm ok with that, since I already know how to do it)

Comment: @RyanStreet Not wanting to be a pain in the A, do you think you'd have some time to look at this please? Thank you

Comment: I will look at it when I have time.  Patience please.

Comment: @RyanStreet No problem. As I've said, I don't want to be a pain it was just a reminder in case you had forgotten for some reason :). Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use any additional phtml file for this. Basically what you need to do is, put your editing html codes in the same file where show html codes reside. But by default this section should be hided. When user click on edit link, you should display the edit content as a popup. In order to do that, you need to use some js tricks.

ie.

```
<!-- customer details show section -->

<div class="customer-show">
    <!-- some codes -->
</div>

<!-- customer editing codes here -->

<div class="customer-edit" style="display:none">
    <!-- customer edit html here -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     /**
      * script to make visible edit section and make it as a popup 
      * comes here.
      */
</script>
```